# Can KingRoot Brick my Nexus 9 and HTC One

Tags: rooting, unbricking, htc-one, nexus-9

Hello Android Enthusiasts,

I was wondering if KingRoot can potentially brick my HTC One and Nexus 9. I have not rooted either yet for my warranty is still active. If either is bricked, is there a way that it could possibly be recovered? If possible, could you please provide me with some statistics or percentages regarding the likeliness of one of these devices becoming bricked? Here are a few more specifications about my devices:

HTC One M8 Harman Kardon Edition from Sprint

HTC Google Nexus 9 (No carrier, WiFi)

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Ani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the answer is:  **any attempt to modify O.S. files can brick your phone**. But you can try to root your phones.  Just make sure you made a full backup of your phone software (not only /data), including boot.img and other sensitive parts of O.S.(system.img and so), and keep those files safe saved on your computer (so you can **reflash** your phone in case something goes wrong). Before attempt to root your device, the oem boot loader must be unlocked. The apk of KingRoot in itself does not produce to much harm on O.S. It just install a necessary **su**  binary to allow getting root access to system, and also some other files. The primary scope of any rooting tool is indeed, placing su somewhere in /system/bin and symlink it (maybe) in /sbin. If you don't know about flashing your device, don't ever try to do things you actually don't master.

Comment: *Just make sure you made a full backup of your phone software* -- but how? I mean without custom recovery, how do you make a **full** backup.

Comment: Firelord, I ussualy use SP Flash Tool for my MTK devices. I am sure there are tools to full backup your system images without root.

Comment: Firelord did you checked this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices

Comment: Yes, I did check. Most of the answers revolves around using ADB for backup and `adb` cannot be used unless Android OS itself is working fine. Also, there is an exception for ADB but that requires custom recovery since stock recoveries doesn't provide such feature. Ultimately, it all comes back to how do you take full backup without custom recovery installed at all. `ADB` AFAIK  doesn't covers everything, just (system+user) apps+app-data+system-settings. This is what I saw by extracting backup.

Comment: SP Flash tool is way ahead in this since it doesn't require Android or recovery to be running while taking the backup. I used it to flash my devices but didn't know that it can take backup as well.

Comment: Firelord, I don't know if the tool works on other platforms, I used only for MTK. But this is the kind of software to be used. I remember using Odin for Samsung:) but those days are far away now.

Comment: Thanks user3344236! I don't plan to flash a custom ROM. Would my device still be bricked in this case?